# Adding a new object to a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array called gradeTable. This array contains grades that fall into the categories of a, q, p, e, and f. I'm trying to create a method that takes in a new grade (i.e. a100, q90, e65) and adds that to the appropriate row. The grade is taken in as a string with the category following the numerical grade. I know I need to create a new array every time a new grade is added, but I'm not sure how to get each grade in it's appropriate spot. The method is a boolean and returns true if the grade is added and false if the category (the letter at the beginning of the string) isn't found. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
public boolean addGrade(String newGradeIn) {     

  char row = newGradeIn.charAt(0);
  int grade = Integer.parseInt(newGradeIn.substring(1));

  gradeTable[row] = Arrays.copyOf(gradeTable[row], gradeTable[row].length + 1);    

 }
```

That's all I have so far. I know it doesn't compile because I don't have a return statement.

Comment: Try ArrayList instead of array, to avoid having to create a new array every time

Comment: I need to use an array.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
String input = /*get user input*/
char cat = input.charAt(0);
int grade = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(1));

int[] oldArr = gradeTable[cat];
int[] newArr = Arrays.copyOf(oldArr, oldArr.length + 1);
newArr[newArr.length - 1] = grade;
gradeTable[cat] = newArr;
```

Comment: @kb94 You are going to have to put in a little legwork yourself here. Do you not understand the code I wrote above? If not, is there something specific you do not understand?

Comment: I don't know much about arrays, and I'm having trouble grasping all of the concepts. I understand the code now. Thanks for your help. I still don't understand how to get the method to return true if a new grade was added and false if it was not.